# If all the money that comes in and out of my account are by means of cheques and credit cards, can I still commit money laundering?

Tags: money-laundering

If I'm not mistaken, paper trail is proof of innocence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can be charged. The criminal act is defined [here](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1956) and [here](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1957). A core defining feature of violation of The Money Laundering Control Act of 1986 is

> knowing that the property involved in a financial transaction
>   represents the proceeds of some form of unlawful activity, conducts or
>   attempts to conduct such a financial transaction which in fact
>   involves the proceeds of specified unlawful activity

So if someone writes you a check funded by drug sales, then you have to worry about the reason for the check. Two of the reasons that will get you in trouble if the transaction is

> (i) with the intent to promote the carrying on of specified unlawful
>   activity; or (ii) with intent to engage in conduct constituting a
>   violation of section 7201 or 7206 of the Internal Revenue Code of
>   1986;

Another reason would be

> knowing that the transaction is designed in whole or in part— (i) to
>   conceal or disguise the nature, the location, the source, the
>   ownership, or the control of the proceeds of specified unlawful
>   activity; or (ii) to avoid a transaction reporting requirement under
>   State or Federal law

A "paper trail" if proof of nothing, it just makes it easier to get caught.

Comment: Thanks. If the the banks behind the cheques and credit cards know more about the transaction than I do, I should be at least more innocent than the banks.